# Is there a config option for non-editable prefixes in entry field

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to make my own console using Tkinter, and I want to be able to display a prefix in the entry field and also use console.prefix("prefix_goes_here") to set said prefix. But when I use entry.set("prefix_goes_here") the user has the ability to delete the prefix.

example of what I mean can be found in CMD

```
C:\Users\Nathan>command_goes_here
```

everything before the ">" is what I would class as the prefix (but I do not know if it has an official name so I am just clarifying).

I also would preferably like to still be able to grab this prefix using entry.get(), but I could store the prefix in a variable and just add it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration option.

One technique is to use the validation feature of an `Entry` widget. In the validation function, you can check that the entry contains the prefix and reject the edit if it does not.

For more example on entry validation see [Interactively validating Entry widget content in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter/4140988#4140988)

### Example

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()

        self.prefix = r'C:\Users\Nathan> '
        vcmd = (root.register(self.onValidate), '%P')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(root, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
        self.entry.insert(0, self.prefix)

    def onValidate(self, P):
        return P.startswith(self.prefix)

e = Example()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I want a fixed prefix, so the back button does not work when it hits the ">" of the prefix (I will automatically put a ">" in font of all prefixes that the user will enter), could I use an if statement to check if there is a ">", and if there isn't then execute a normal backspace?

Comment: @NaNdy: I don't know what you mean. This won't won't let you backspace over the > or any other character in the prefix. It will let you enter any characters you want after the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Although i didnt find exactly what you are asking, i would suggest using 2 entry widgets one next to the other
without borders.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
e = tk.Entry(root)
e.configure(state="normal",borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0)
e.insert(tk.END, "C:\\Users\\Nathan>")
e.configure(bg='white')
e.place(x=0,y=0)
e2 = tk.Entry(root)
e2.configure(bg='white',borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0)
e2.place(x=97,y=0)
e2.config(state="normal")
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Would a label be better in that scenario?

Comment: You could also use labels but i think with Entries it looks better